# iOS 8 Can't locate sqlite File When using CoreData

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I was using my iPhone to run the project. 
here is my Code:

```
  NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

    NSString *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *dataStorePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewsData.sqlite"];
    NSURL *dataStoreURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataStorePath];

    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataStorePath];
    NSLog(@"%@",fileExists);
    sqlite3 *db;
    if (sqlite3_open([dataStorePath UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);

    }
```

the Bool Type 'fileExists' is true,but when i use Finder to locate the sqlite file,it doesn't work.
Anybody can help me ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run it on your iPhone you can't access the file directly because the path `dataStorePath` is on your device.

What you can do is that you download the app container via Xcode: First connect your iPhone. Then go to Xcode->Window->Devices in the menu and select your iPhone on the left side. Your app should appear in the "Installed Apps"-list. Select it and click on the settings button (next to the add and delete button) and click on "Download Container...". Xcode will ask you where you want to save it. Afterwards do a right click on the downloaded container in the finder and select "Show Package Contents". Go to AppData->Documents and you will see your sqlite file "NewsData.sqlite".

By the way, if you run in the simulator you can open the link directly with the finder.

Comment: Thank you very much,with your steps , problem solved.